# About the meaning of Step Function

Tags: real-analysis

I saw a problem like the following:

Construct an non-negative step function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is integrable on $\mathbb{R}$ but $\limsup_{x\to\infty}f(x)=+\infty$.

My question is: according to definition, a step function is a finite linear combination of indicator functions, which can take only finitely many (finite) values. How could it be possible that $\limsup_{x\to\infty}f(x)=+\infty$? Can anyone give me some explanations or hints? Many thanks!

Comment: My guess is that there are different conventions for the definition of the step function. The wikipedia article follows the convention of finitely many steps, but it also mentions that some authors allow infinite steps.

Comment: One is probably supposed to find a solution whose restriction to every bounded interval is a step function. Can you do that?